# Quelle serait la meilleure formulation de « feel free » en français ?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Lorsque j'utilise l'anglais, j'utilise souvent la formulation « feel free », qui a pour sens « ne vous gênez pas pour », mais qui contrairement au français est positive et encourage la personne.

Comme par exemple :

> Feel free to ask.

qui encourage à poser une question si l'on en a une.

Je n'arrive pas à trouver une expression qui exprime cela en français et j'aimerais savoir si vous en connaissez une.

Comment: Une question plus récente : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33630/feel-free-et-nh%c3%a9sitez-pas

Answer (score 10):

J'utiliserais le terme "hésiter". On entend parfois en conférence un orateur dire :

> N'hésitez pas à m'interrompre pour poser des questions

On peut aussi indiquer qu'on est disponible/qu'on ne sera pas dérangé par une demande :

> Je me tiens à votre disposition pour tout complément d'information
>
> Mon bureau est ouvert pour répondre à vos questions

La traduction la plus littérale n'est cependant pas fausse :

> Sentez-vous libre de m'interrompre pour intervenir.

Comment: Merci pour ces suggestions, mais la vérité est que je les trouve très formelles. Il est vrai que l'expression peut être utilisée pour exprimer quelque chose de formel, mais le côté ouvert et agréagle de la formulation n'y est pas. Concernant la traduction littérale elle est un peu étrange bien que faisant sens.

Comment: Bien répondu (+1). Pour la dernière version proposée on pourrait aussi avoir *« Soyez libre de ... »*. @Kiwy la formulation *N'hésitez pas à ...* n'est pas si formelle, elle est idiomatique et très employée.

Comment: « Sentez-vous libre … » me semble par contre très étrange ; si je le croisais dans un texte, je parierais sur une traduction (médiocre) d’un texte anglais.

Comment: @Edouard Oui c'est trop littéral, d'où ma proposition avec *Soyez*.

Comment: La première et la dernière formulation ne sont pas formelles. En outre, vous pouvez nuancer en plaçant un terme marquant une intrusion/impolitesse (comme "interrompre") pour justement montrer que vous ne vous formalisez pas.

Comment: @Edouard: "sentez-vous" se dit (vous vous sentez bien ?) mais je dois reconnaître que j'ai eu la même impression que vous après l'avoir écrite... mais comme on en trouve pléthore...

Comment: @RomainVALERI Ce qui me dérange dans la formulation `n'hésiter pas` c'est qu'elle utilise une forme négative quand ce que je veux exprimer est un message positif et très ouvert. Je trouve que cela ne rend pas justice à la "gentilesse" véhiculée par l'expression `feel free`

Comment: @mansuetus Peut-être est-ce l’emploi de l’impératif avec le verbe « se sentir » qui sonne faux, tout simplement. Difficile d’ordonner à quelqu’un de ressentir quelque chose.

Comment: @Kiwy Negatived turns of phrase are known to be more frequent in French than English, and you'll find the reverse too from time to time: *laissez-moi rire* -> *don't make me laugh*, *ça m'est égal* -> *I don't mind*. According to my translation manual (with a chapter on the topic), on average almost 1 in 5 negative in the French version of a translation corresponds to a non-negative turn in the English.

Comment: @Circeus I don't like that :D but the more I know idiomatic expression in english the more I'm frustrated with those nice english expression when I want to express them in french

Comment: @Kiwy personnellement, si on me dit *n'hésitez pas* je n'y vois rien de négatif, bien au contraire. C'est pour moi la façon naturelle d'exprimer quelque chose de très similaire voire tout aussi gentil que *feel free*.

Answer (score 3):

En français de Belgique, on emploie parfois la locution « à votre aise » :

> Faites à votre aise, posez les questions que vous voulez.
>
> — Est-ce que je peux ouvrir la fenêtre ?
>   — À votre aise.

Je ne sais pas si c'est d'usage dans d'autres pays francophones (en tout cas pas en France).

Comment: En France aussi, mais cela sonne plus désué en France qu'en Belgique c'est sûr.

Answer (score 1):

C'est normal que les propositions de [la réponse de mansuetus](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/9154/364) soient plutôt formelles: quand le contexte n'est pas formel, personne n'hésite à demander et *feel free to ask* n'a pas besoin d'être exprimé.

Il y a cependant une façon de dire qui n'est pas si formelle:

> Vous pouvez poser des questions.

Comment: mon exemple porte sur `feel free` pas sur `ask question`. `Feel free to bother`, `feel free to come by`, `feel free to call`, `feel free to have sex`, les exemples ne manquent pas.

Comment: Ma réponse aussi. _Tu peux_ / _Vous pouvez_ restent valables dans d'autres contextes.

Comment: Malheureusement cela ne rends pas le côté encourageant de l'expression, `feel free` représente vraiment une incitation en cas de besoin alors que `pouvoir` va représenter une autorisation donc une formulation plus formelle.