# "Feel free" et "N'hésitez pas"

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, université

En anglais l'on peut dire :

> Please feel free to contact me if you have any questions.

En français pourrait-on dire :

> S'il vous plaît n'hésitez pas à me contacter si vous avez des questions.
>
> S'il vous plaît n'hésitez pas de me contacter si vous avez des questions.
>
> ...Une autre phrase d'un registre plus familier

s’adressant aux étudiant.e.s ?

Comment: Une question similaire : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9153/quelle-serait-la-meilleure-formulation-de-feel-free-en-fran%c3%a7ais

Answer (score 7, accepted):

« N'hésitez pas à me contacter si vous avez des questions. »

*Hésiter* se construit avec *à*, pas *de*.

On ne dirait pas « s'il vous plaît » dans cette phrase parce que « s'il vous plaît » donnerait l'impression qu'on demande de faire quelque chose. Par exemple, on pourrait dire « Veuillez me contacter par courriel si vous avez des questions, s'il vous plaît », parce qu'il y a implicitement une demande de ne pas utiliser un moyen de communication autre que le courriel. Mais même dans cette phrase « veuillez » est d'un niveau de politesse suffisant et on ne rajouterait en général pas « s'il vous plaît ».